# Thuuldom spells

Tags: trudvang-chronicles

Does Thuuldom dimwalker have to learn all previous levels of rune in order to learn, for example, level 3? I mean - it is necessary to learn levels 1 and 2 before?

All other religions have few spells for each holy tablet level, but in the chapter with Thuuldom spells, none of them has level specified so I suppose that dimwalker has to learn each rune separately.

Comment: Hello and welcome to RPGSE. Please add the tags appropriate to the system and edition your question applies to.

Comment: Hi. I tried to but there is no tag for Trudvang Chronicles and there is a requirement of 300 rep in order to create own tag.

Comment: OK, new tag added. What should I add to the tag wiki?

Comment: Bear in mind: we don't close questions as unclear for *not having the tags*. We close them as unclear when we don't know what game they're about, but that information was present in the question text we were given. We as curators can then add appropriate tags (as was done).

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.